# Spring and bean scope, services should be singletons and dao's should be per request?

Tags: java, spring, scope

Within a spring mvc application, is the following scope for each bean type correct?

```
1. service's which have properties that are Dao's be singleton?
2. Dao's that reference a data source should be per request scope.
```

Does this make sound sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, DAOs should also be singletons. If your DAOs have state, you are doing something wrong.

If you have multiple DataSources per DAO type that's a problem, but to me the solution is to have one singleton per datasource.

Comment: And datasource is also a singleton b/c is supports thread pools right?